# Сохранение файлов в новый каталог используя pillow, os

Tags: python, ос, pillow

как сохранить обработанные файлы по новому пути:
есть код:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

    dir = os.path.abspath('/Path_to_files')
    resize = os.path.abspath('/Path_to_new_files')
    
    for f in os.scandir(dir):
        if f.is_file() and f.path.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'jpg':
            image = Image.open(f.path)
            image.save()
```

Как в цикле сохранить все файлы в каталог "resize", без изменения имен файлов?

Comment: image.save( f'{os.path.join(outDir, outFileName)}.png', 'PNG', compress_level=self.compressLevel)

Answer (score 0):

Ларчик все-же просто открывался:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

dir = os.path.abspath('/path_to_files')
resize = os.path.abspath('/path_to_new_files/{}') 

for f in os.scandir(dir):
    if f.is_file() and f.path.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'jpg':
        image = Image.open(f.path)
        image.save(resize.format(f.name))
```